# SQL - Select Union All Giving Wrong Order

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two stored procudures. Where Condition Logic for two of the stored procedures are same. But Join tables, Select columns are different for two of the stored procedures.

The SP is Like Below.

```
  Select a, b, c, d, e From Table (Join Logic) where (Conditions)
  Union All
  Select a, b, c, d, e From Table (Join Logic) where (Conditions)
  Union All
  Select a, b, c, d, e From Table (Join Logic) where (Conditions).
```

I have not used any order By. The only differencr between two SPs are select columns & Join
tables are different.

But SP1 & SP2 results orders are different only for one or two records. Why is it happening Like this.
Because of Union All, any Auto order By  has taken Place?

If i use Distinct in select statment i am getting correct Order.

Can any one please let me know what is causing this order alignment?

Comment: You can analyze execution plan - this could halp you to find difference and answer for this question. I think that optimizer gets other field to sort order bacause maybe you missed some index or FK in tables wich are used in JOIN? Wihtout full DB schema it's hard to suggest something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an explicit `ORDER BY`, no ordering is guaranteed. Period

Do not rely on an ordering unless you have an `ORDER BY`; it may change at a future date.